# Why my buttons doesnt behave properly in live server in vscode?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
    display(data[0].skills, 0, -2, data, 1);//function called
/* display function */
    function display(skillValue, g, editvalue, data, toggle)
    { 
    dataArr.push(<button 
    onclick="edit(${i},${toggle})">Edit</button>);
    }
    function edit(g, toggle) {
    skillValue = ` <label for="fname"></label> <input 
    type="text" id="fname" name="fname">`;
    display(skillValue, g, 1, data, toggle);
       
    }
```

Comment: You're missing the backticks around the button to make it a template literal.

Answer (score 0):

as Barmar suggestaed on the comment its because you are trying to push the button to the array not as a string.

look at the line: `dataArr.push`

```
    display(data[0].skills, 0, -2, data, 1);//function called
/* display function */
    function display(skillValue, g, editvalue, data, toggle)
    { 
    dataArr.push(`<button 
    onclick="edit(${i},${toggle})">Edit</button>`);
    }
    function edit(g, toggle) {
    skillValue = ` <label for="fname"></label> <input 
    type="text" id="fname" name="fname">`;
    display(skillValue, g, 1, data, toggle);
       
    }
```